How to calculate sales in last 30 weeks in DAX by taking off the current context and subtracting weeks?
I have a custom calendar table with date, year, week number, year week.
There is another table called FactSales
Example: 2024, 5, Y24 W05
I want to create a table visual with 4 columns. Year week, sales in that week, sum of sales in previous 30 weeks, sum of sales in previous 52 weeks.
Sales in that week = sum(FactSales['salesamt'])

Sales in previous 30 weeks = 
var curryear=MAX(calendar[year])
var currweek=MAX(calendar[week number])
Return CALCULATE([Sales in that week], calendar[week number]>=currweek-30)

Sales in previous 52 weeks = 
var curryear=MAX(calendar[year])
var currweek=MAX(calendar[week number])
Return 
CALCULATE([Sales in that week], calendar[week number]>=currweek-52)

I'm facing 2 problem with this approach.
One is I'm not sure how to take out the filter context of current row. For example - should I use ALL(calendar) or ALL(calendar[date]) or ALL(calendar[year week]) or ALL(sales[saledate]) in the following DAX to get rid of the current week context of the table visual row.
CALCULATE([Sales in that week], calendar[week number]>=currweek-30)
The second problem is that - say we are in week 10. Subtracting 30 from 10 results in negative week number. How to handle such case?

https://www.daxpatterns.com/week-related-calculations/

Interesting but if you see the answer from Ryan then that appears simpler. How do I decide which approach to use?

here is a workaround for you.

create a yearweek column
yearweek = 'Table'[year]*100+'Table'[week]

create a rank column
rank = rankx(all('Table'),'Table'[yearweek],,ASC)



then even if the week skip to another year, the rank column will not break.
you can use rank column to get previous 30 weeks or 52 weeks

How about if I subtract 365 from today, identity the year week, then get the first date of the week. This is the first date 52 weeks ago.

I would suggest to use Time Itelligence Functions for your query:
SUMMARIZE(
  calendar, 
  calendar[Year_Week], 
  "Sales Week", sum(FactSales['salesamt']), 
  "Sales 30 Weeks before", CALCULATE(sum(FactSales['salesamt']), DATESINPERIOD(calendar[Day], min(calendar[Day]), -7 * 30, DAY)),
  "Sales 50 Weeks before", CALCULATE(sum(FactSales['salesamt']), DATESINPERIOD(calendar[Day], min(calendar[Day]), -7 * 50, DAY)),
) 


if you want to get 365 from today, try to create a flag column
Column =
VAR _start =
    MAXX ( FILTER ( 'date', 'date'[Date] = ( TODAY () - 365 ) ), 'date'[yearweek] )
RETURN
    IF (
        'date'[yearweek] >= _start
            && 'date'[yearweek]
                <= MAXX ( FILTER ( 'date', 'date'[Date] = TODAY () ), 'date'[yearweek] ),
        1,
        0
    )


